# Word vbscript row height issue

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

I'm just trying to have the bottom of the table "hug" the bottom of the text in the row. Currently, it seems to be an extra line below the text. I copied the signature with the table into Word and I was able to get the line to be flush with the bottom by changing the Row height is: Exactly - 0.5". However, I've tried to accomplish this with vbscript using various variations of RowHeight, SetHeight, etc and I can't seem to get it to stick.  This is my last step! Any suggestions? :)

Here's my code:

```
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

strUser = objSysInfo.UserName
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUser)

strName = objUser.FullName
strFirst = objUser.FirstName
strLast = objUser.LastName
strInitials = objUser.Initials
strOffice = objUser.physicalDeliveryOfficeName
strPOBox = objUser.postOfficeBox
strTitle = objUser.Description
strCred = objUser.info
strStreet = objUser.StreetAddress
strLocation = objUser.l
strPostCode = objUser.PostalCode
strPhone = objUser.TelephoneNumber
strMobile = objUser.Mobile
strFax = objUser.FacsimileTelephoneNumber
strEmail = objUser.mail
strCompany = objUser.Company

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Const END_OF_STORY = 6

Const NUMBER_OF_ROWS = 1
Const NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 2

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

Set objEmailOptions = objWord.EmailOptions
Set objSignatureObject = objEmailOptions.EmailSignature

Set objSignatureEntries = objSignatureObject.EmailSignatureEntries

Set objRange = objDoc.Range()
objDoc.Tables.Add objRange, NUMBER_OF_ROWS, NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS
Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(1)

Dim rngCell
Set rngCell = objTable.Cell(1, 2).Range
objTable.Columns(1).Width = 50
objTable.Columns(2).Width = 360
rngCell.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
rngCell.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceExactly
rngCell.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = 12
rngCell.Text = strFirst & " " & strInitials & " " & strLast & " | " & _
               strOffice & " | " & strCompany & vbCr
rngCell.Font.Bold = True
rngCell.Font.Name = "Calibri"
rngCell.Font.Size = 10
rngCell.Collapse 0  'wdCollapseEnd
rngCell.MoveEnd 1, -1  'wdCharacter, 1
rngCell.Text = strStreet & " | " & strPOBox & " | " & strLocation & vbCr
rngCell.Font.Bold = False
rngCell.Font.Name = "Calibri"
rngCell.Font.Size = 10
rngCell.Collapse 0  'wdCollapseEnd
rngCell.MoveEnd 1, -1  'wdCharacter, 1
rngCell.Text = vbCr & "Phone: " & strPhone & " | " & "Fax: " & strFax & " | " & "Email: " & vbCr
rngCell.Font.Bold = False
rngCell.Font.Name = "Calibri"
rngCell.Font.Size = 10
rngCell.Collapse 0  'wdCollapseEnd
rngCell.MoveEnd 1, -1  'wdCharacter, 1
Set objLink = objTable.Cell(1, 2).Range
objLink.Hyperlinks.Add rngCell, "mailto:" & strEmail,,,strEmail
objLink.Font.Size = 10
objLink.Font.Name = "Calibri"
objSelection.EndKey END_OF_STORY
objSelection.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0

Set objSelection = objDoc.Range()

objSignatureEntries.Add "Reply Signature", objSelection
objSignatureObject.ReplyMessageSignature = "Reply Signature"

objDoc.Saved = True
objWord.Quit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helpless ol' me fixed the issue I was having with this:

```
objSelection.EndKey END_OF_STORY
objSelection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 0
objSelection.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
objSelection.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceExactly
objSelection.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = 1
objSelection.Font.Size = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Recording a macro gave me HeightRule and Height as the key properties for setting a table row's height. From your problem description it appears you're missing the `HeightRule`, which needs to be set to `wdRowHeightExactly` (for VBScript the Enum integer equivalent: 2). For example:

```
Dim rw as Word.Row
Set rw = objTable.Rows(1)
rw.HeightRule = 2  'wdRowHeightExactly
rw.Height = 72     'InchesToPoints(1)
```

Comment: For some reason that just makes the first column's image smaller.  It doesn't have any effect on the row height.

Comment: Actually, if I increase the number above 72, the row height will increase.  If I change the number anywhere between 32 and 72, it doesn't nothing.  If I decrease the number any lower than 32, it starts making the image(company logo) in the first column smaller and doesn't change the row height at all.

Comment: Your question was, how to set an exact height. I answered that and also explained you can use the Macro Recorder to get this kind of information. I preface my code snippet with "for example", and if you read the comments in my code you'll see it sets InchesToPoints(1) = 1". You need to adjust that to what you need, and you need to find out how many points the setting you want is. You can do that in Word's VBA Editor's (Alt+F11) Immediate Window (Ctrl+G) by typing the following, then pressing Enter: ?InchesToPoints([number of inches]).

Comment: StackOverflow is NOT a free code-writing or tutorial service - I'm giving you the tutorial "for free", but you are expected to make some effort of your own when incorporating the information you get here...